# How to render an input widget in a collapsed menu item?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to render a checkbox menu in a collapsed menu item in shinydashboard, but I cannot get it to work. So far, I have only found an similar [github issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/42) when rendering to the `dashboardBody`, but I couldn't figure out how that would apply to the `siderbarMenu`.

```
library('shiny')
library("shinydashboard")

header <- dashboardHeader()

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Inputs", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"), tabName = "tabOne",
             uiOutput('mymenu')
    )
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  h3('nothing here')
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body),
  server = function(input, output) {


    output$mymenu <- renderUI({

      checkboxGroupInput('mymenu', 'lettersMenu',
                         letters[1:5],
                         letters[1:5])
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that there is nothing triggering this `renderUI`. Try adding this to your code:

```
outputOptions(output, "mymenu", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```

## edit

```
library('shiny')
library("shinydashboard")

header <- dashboardHeader()

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Inputs", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"), tabName = "tabOne",
             uiOutput('mymenu')
    )
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  h3('nothing here')
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body),
  server = function(input, output) {


    output$mymenu <- renderUI({

      checkboxGroupInput('mymenu', 'lettersMenu',
                         letters[1:5],
                         letters[1:5])
    })
    outputOptions(output, "mymenu", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  }
)
```

Comment: Where? Also, why do I need to trigger `renderUI`? I was able to render the menu with basically the same code without using `shinydashboard`.

Comment: This code would be placed inside `server()` but outside `output$mymenu`.

Comment: Sadly, I can't explain why this code works... but I had a similar problem last week and that's how I solved it...

Comment: Doesn't work for me, could you post a compete solution? It says `Error : object 'output' not found`

Comment: Edited in the answer